# stdout to tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I redirect stdout data to a tkinter Text widget?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make a file-like class whose `write` method writes to the Tkinter widget instead, and then do `sys.stdout = <your new class>`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914603/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-while-redirecting-sys-stdout-to-tkinter-text-wi).

Example (copied from the link):

```
class IORedirector(object):
    '''A general class for redirecting I/O to this Text widget.'''
    def __init__(self,text_area):
        self.text_area = text_area

class StdoutRedirector(IORedirector):
    '''A class for redirecting stdout to this Text widget.'''
    def write(self,str):
        self.text_area.write(str,False)
```

and then, in your Tkinter widget:

```
# To start redirecting stdout:
import sys
sys.stdout = StdoutRedirector( self )
# (where self refers to the widget)

# To stop redirecting stdout:
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Comment: Hi! Could you maybe provide me with an example? I'm very new with python and I'm struggling to get this to work. Much obliged :)

Comment: The linked question has all the code you need, I think. You need to make your own version of the class `StdoutRedirector` as is done there, then set `sys.stdout = StdoutRedirector`. I'll copy the code into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I found a solution which I would like to share with the community. My example pipes a listing of the working directory to a Tk window. I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 8. I ran the code through both Jupyter Notebook and Eclipse using Pydev.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

def ls_proc():
    return Popen(['ls'], stdout=PIPE)

with ls_proc() as p:
    if p.stdout:
        for line in p.stdout:
            text.insert(END, line)
    if p.stderr:
        for line in p.stderr:
            text.insert(END, line)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
log_box_1 = tk.Text(root, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken")

with subprocess.Popen("ls -la", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                log_box_1.insert(tk.END, line)
```

From [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=5gxTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=how%20to%20set%20popen%20stdout%20to%20a%20tkinter%20text&source=bl&ots=lO0NPnalhq&sig=ACfU3U319-Q8DV6M4GwPaFb0-HyzPjQdHg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv06nvzuniAhVpIrkGHZNXC_gQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20set%20popen%20stdout%20to%20a%20tkinter%20text&f=false)