# How to show the console output in a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, stdout

I have a program which downloads data from the internet and I have already implemented a GUI in the user-credential grabber so after a user enters the credentials, the program starts downloading through a console but I want to display the output through a Tkinter GUI so I have a `Tkinter.Text()` widget waiting to receive and write data to the GUI but how do I send data which is written in the console or the standard output stream

Comment: Do you want to show the data as they are downloading or after the downloading completes? If you want to show the data after download completes, store the data in a variable and show in GUI.

Comment: I want to show the data as they are downloading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question correctly. Would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333334/stdout-to-tkinter-gui) help you?