# Printing out information with python?

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to print out information into this window and not in the console. How do I do this?

```
from tkinter import *

print("Hello")
gui = Tk(className='StreetView Map')
# set window size
gui.geometry("500x200")

gui.mainloop()
```

I tried using the print function but nothing showed up in the window.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010703/send-the-output-of-print-to-tkinter-text-widget.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to ask two different questions (how to display text and how to show an iframe). Please create a separate post for each issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Label`.

```py
Label(gui, text="Hello").pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create a Text widget where you can insert the test on GUI on Tkinter.

Given your code it would have to be done like this.

```
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk(className='StreetView Map')

# set window size
gui.geometry("500x200")

T = Text(root, height = 5, width = 52)
T.pack()

#insert the string in Text Widget
T.insert(tk.END, "hello")

gui.mainloop()
```