# How to replace standard input () with flask form in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

My question is similar to [Replacing input() portions of a Python program in a GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524631/replacing-input-portions-of-a-python-program-in-a-gui). But I need a web UI not desktop UI(tkinter based solution as answered in the link)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a webpage with `HTML/CSS` and create a form in it to get the input. Then, you will have to link the webpage with your backend (flask) to receive the input in python and manipulate as needed. Following a [tutorial like this one](https://overiq.com/flask-101/form-handling-in-flask/) will help you get started. Or, you can simply search the web for **"Form handling in Flask"** to find something that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Say you're asking for the user to input their username. You'd do something like this.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" value="{{ request.form.username }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

Whatever you want to call your variable, you put after request.form

In your program (where you import flask), also import request from flask like so:

`from flask import request`

Under your route's function, check if the request's method is POST and assign your form variable:

```
def index():
  if request.method == "POST":
    foo = request.form["username"]
  return render_template("index.html")
```

So when the user clicks the submit button, `foo` will be whatever they put in the text box.

You can see more at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#accessing-request-data