# Capture python stdout in real time

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, stdout

I have a GUI program `guy.py` (that uses tkinter) and a command line script `script.py`. I want to launch the script from the program and write its output to a textbox in the GUI. Because the script takes quite some time to run (up to 15 minutes), and I want to monitor it, I want the script to write the output in real time inside the textbox, while it's being written, not just when it has finished executing.

I've found some [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333386) dealing with this problem. Here is the code of `gui.py` I've developed until now (the real code is too big to post here, but here's the most important part)

```py
import tkinter as tk

# redirector class
class StdoutRedirector:
    def __init__(self, textbox):
        self.textbox = textbox

    def write(self, str):
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, str)

# gui application
class GuiApp:
    def __init__():
        self._out = StdoutRedirector(self.builder.get_object('textbox1')) # this just takes a reference to the tkinter text

    def button_callback(self):
        sys.stdout = self._out
        print("test") # this will print to the textbox
        subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'script.py']) # this will not print to the textbox
```

This will print the output to the "normal" output, so I've tried telling subprocess what to use as stdout, by changing the last line to

```py
subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'script.py'], stdout=self._out)
```

This results in an exception, because (differently from `print()`), `Popen()` needs a file descriptor. Of course giving a `fileno` of 1 will just print to stdout, giving any other number will throw an error

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./guy.py", line 64, in convert_sdatb
    subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'test_subprocess.py'], stdout=self._out)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 808, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1489, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
AttributeError: 'StdoutRedirector' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

How can I make that the output of my script is redirected in real time (as it's written) directly in my class?

Comment: You would need to specify `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, and then periodically call `.read()` on that pipe and write to your textbox.